# Submitting value on hidden field with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have hidden field.

```
  <hidden id="city-sel" name="city" class="input-large"></hidden>
```

It's initialized with Select2 to do a dynamic lookup for city, and that's working fine.

```
function c_enable(state, text) {
  $("#city-sel").select2({
      placeholder: text,
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      query: function(query) {
        $.ajax({
          url:city_url(query.term),
          dataType:'json'              
        }).done(function(data) {
          query.callback({results: data});
        })
      }
    });

  $("#city-sel").select2(state);
}
```

The problem is when the form is submitted, the value from this field is not submitted. How to make this work?

Comment: have you tried using `<input type='hidden'` instead of `<hidden`.

Comment: there is no tag called `<hidden>` use `<input type='hidden'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important point that you have to know is, whenever a form gets submitted, it sends all the `<input` tags and only those which has `name` attribute. It is like a key-value map with the input names as keys and their values as values.

And here in your code you just need to change:

```
<hidden id="city-sel" name="city" class="input-large"></hidden>
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" id="city-sel" name="city" class="input-large"></input>
```

the whole idea of using `hidden` fields to submit `select` tags, is based on this very point.

Comment: Wow, talk about a bone-headed mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With valid HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="city-sel" name="city" class="input-large"/>
```